# Algorithm for GRG2 method of solving non-linear least square

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have been looking for quite a while for an algorithm for the GRG2 method either in a .net assembly or an algorithm I could program myself, but I can't find a decent representation of the algorithm to work with.

Does anyone here have any resources they would be willing to share?

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer the question I put a bounty on, but try the free [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524509%28v=vs.93%29). Microsoft Excel's [Solver uses the GRG2 algorithm](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82890) by default, and with MSF you have a .NET API for it. Note that it is not dependent on Excel in any way though.

Comment: Wow. I will check this out tonight, but if it works I owe you big time.

Comment: I am not totally sure it is using GRG2 but whatever it does it seems to work just as well. I got some help on using it at StackOverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303094/how-can-i-emulate-microsoft-excels-solver-functionality-grg-nonlinear-in-c).

Comment: Any chance you could check into this ASAP so I can get my bounty back if it is a viable solution? ;-)

Comment: I havent gotten it to work yet, but its given me a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The following article mentions OpenMI and GRG2 method:
http://www.openmi-life.org/events/secondWorkshop/UTH_2nd_OpenMI_Life_Workshop.pdf